# Dyck paths with $k$ peaks

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

There are $n$ $1$'s and $n$ $0$'s.
We have to arrange them in a row such that at no position in this row the number of $0$'s from the beginning exceed the number of $1$'s from the beginning.
Also the number of occasions when a $1$ is immediately followed by a $0$ should be exactly $k$.
In how many ways can they be arranged?

Comment: Catalan numbers give us a way to determine the number of ways we can arrange N 0s and N 1s in a row such that at no position in this row the number of 0s from the beginning exceed the number of 1s from the beginning.Let us call every instance when a 1 is immediately followed by a 0 as a violation.So we have to find the number of arrangements with exactly K violations, however, the catalan numbers will consist of arrangements with number of violations ranging from 1 to n.

Comment: Now that you've said this, do you want to see how to show this, or did you just answer your own question?

Comment: Catalan numbers will count extra cases.Nth catalan number will count arrangements with number of violations ranging from 1 to n.However we are interested in knowing the number of arrangements with exactly k violation.PS: By violation i mean every instance when a 1 is immediately followed by a 0

Answer (score 10):

Let the number of paths be $f(n,k)$; by actual computation we find the following values for $f(n,k)$ for $1\le k\le n\le 5$:

$$\begin{array}{l|cc}
n\backslash k&1&2&3&4&5\\ \hline
1&1\\
2&1&1\\
3&1&3&1\\
4&1&6&6&1\\
5&1&10&20&10&1
\end{array}$$

Looking this up in [OEIS](http://oeis.org/), we find that it appears to be [OEIS A$001263$](http://oeis.org/A001263), the triangle of [Narayana numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narayana_number). This is confirmed by the second comment, which identifies $f(n,k)$ as the number of Dyck $n$-paths with exactly $k$ peaks. As noted at both links,

$$f(n,k)=\frac1n\binom{n}k\binom{n}{k-1}\;.$$

**Added:** If $b=b_1\ldots b_{2n}$ is such a sequence, let $b^+=1b_1\ldots b_{2n}$; $b^+$ has $n+1$ $1$’s and $n$ $0$’s, and it also has exactly $k$ instances of a $1$ immediately followed by a $0$. Clearly $b_{2n}=0$, so $$b^+=1^{p_1}0^{q_1}1^{p_2}0^{q_2}\ldots 1^{p_k}0^{q_k}$$ for some positive integers $p_i$ and $q_i$ such that $p_1+\ldots+p_k=n+1$ and $q_1+\ldots+q_k=n$. There are $\binom{n}{k-1}$ compositions of $n+1$ with $k$ parts and $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ compositions of $n$ with $k$ parts, so there are $\binom{n}{k-1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ pairs of $k$-part compositions $p_1+\ldots+p_k=n+1$ and $q_1+\ldots+q_k=n$. Each pair gives rise to a sequence $1^{p_1}0^{q_1}1^{p_2}0^{q_2}\ldots 1^{p_k}0^{q_k}$, but this sequence may not be $b^+$ for any admissible $2n$-sequence $b$.

Say that two sequences of $n+1$ $1$’s and $n$ $0$’s matching the (generalized) regular expression $(1^+0^+)^k$ are equivalent if they generate the same circular sequence; this clearly is an equivalence relation, and each equivalence class has $k$ elements. (E.g., $1^{p_3}0^{q_3}1^{p_4}0^{q_4}\ldots 1^{p_k}0^{q_k}1^{p_1}0^{q_1}1^{p_2}0^{q_2}$ is equivalent to $1^{p_1}0^{q_1}1^{p_2}0^{q_2}\ldots 1^{p_k}0^{q_k}$.) [Raney’s lemma](http://fileadmin.cs.lth.se/cs/Personal/Rolf_Karlsson/km/lect6.pdf) [PDF, p. 5] (= [Cycle Lemma](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~nachumd/papers/CL.pdf) [PDF] with $k=1$) implies that exactly one of the $2n+1$ circular shifts of $1^{p_1}0^{q_1}1^{p_2}0^{q_2}\ldots 1^{p_k}0^{q_k}$ is $b^+$ for some admissible $2n$-sequence $b$. (To see this, just replace each $0$ by $-1$.) It’s clear that this shift must be one of the $k$ matching the pattern $(0^+1^+)^k$, so each equivalence class contains exactly one sequence that is $b^+$ for some admissible $2n$-sequence $b$. Thus, there are $$\frac1k\binom{n}{k-1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}=\frac1n\binom{n}{k-1}\binom{n}k$$ admissible $2n$-sequences.

(This argument is my slight adaptation of Richard P. Stanley’s solution to Exercise $36$(a) of the excerpt on problems relating to Catalan numbers taken from Volume $2$ of his *Enumerative Combinatorics*; the excerpt and solutions can be downloaded from [this page](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/).)

Comment: Yes the answer seems to be narayana numbers, but how do we prove it? Can we derive some recurrence for narayana numbers...and how do we show that they are symmetrical for k and n-k+1(as can be seen from the formula) if the proof could be built on that

Comment: @user103260: I did prove it: that’s the material that I added.

Comment: sorry slow internet connection here,going through it...but i have  an intuition that it can be proved using recurrences in a much less rigorous way.

Comment: @user103260: Stanley rates the problem of showing that there are $\frac1n\binom{n}{k-1}\binom{n}k$ such sequences 2+, meaning that it’s about as hard a problem as one could reasonably ask graduate students to solve, and only some would solve it. I’m sure that there are other ways to prove it, but they probably aren’t any easier to find. It is fairly easy to see that $f(n,1)=f(n,n)=1$ and $f(n+1,2)=f(n,2)=n$ for all $n\ge 1$, but $f(n+1,n)=f(n+1,2)$ already seems significantly harder.

Comment: Thanks Brian.But could you simplify the proof a bit, i dont get the division by k.You have multiplied the number of k partitions of n+1 1's and k partitions of n 0's.But this will contain cases when the power of 0 is greater than the power of 1 which it immediately follows.So i guess that division takes this into care.But how? please help, thanks.

Comment: @user103260: The division by $k$ is precisely because each equivalence class contains only one admissible sequence: it compensates for what would otherwise be $k$-fold overcounting. I don’t see any way to simplify the argument. I might be able to rewrite it in a way that makes it a little easier to grasp, but if I can, I probably won’t get to it until tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks brian, looking forward to a simpler explanation!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: There is at least a generating function solution. It requires a generating function on two variables, and it is a bit lengthy if one includes all the steps.

Answer (score 3):

This argument is an expansion of my argument made for sci.math regarding the question not counting the peaks. I have kept the steps small, at the expense of the length of the derivations.

**[Recurrence Relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation)**

Instead of $0$ and $1$, let's use $-1$ and $+1$.

Let us call an arrangement of $n$ '$+1$'s and $n$ '$-1$'s, with $p$ occurrences of $+1-1$ (peaks), a walk of type $n,p$. Let us also call a walk that has no negative partial sum a unilateral walk.

Let $w(n,p)$ be the number of unilateral walks of type $n,p$.  Let us classify these
walks by the type of their smallest initial subwalk.  Those whose smallest
initial subwalk is of type $k,m$ look like either like this:
$$
+1-1\langle\text{a unilateral walk of type }n-1,p-1\rangle
$$
or like this:
$$
+1\langle\text{a unilateral walk of type }k-1,m\rangle-1\langle\text{a unilateral walk of type }n-k,p-m\rangle
$$
By considering all possible types of initial subwalk, we get the following recurrence relation:
$$
w(n,p)=\overbrace{\vphantom{\sum_{k=1}^n}w(n-1,p-1)}^{+1-1\langle\text{type }n-1,p-1\rangle}
+\overbrace{\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{m=1}^pw(k-1,m)w(n-k,p-m)}^{+1\langle\text{type }k-1,m\rangle-1\langle\text{type }n-k,p-m\rangle}\tag{1}
$$
with the initial conditions that $w(0,0)=1$ and $w(n,0)=0$ if $n\gt0$; that is, the only walk without any peaks is the empty walk, and $w(n,p)=0$ if $p\gt n$; that is, there can't be more peaks than $+1$s.

---

**Closed Form for the [Generating Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)**

Note that $g(0,y)=1$ and for $n\gt0$:
$$
\begin{align}
g(n,y)
&=\sum_{p=1}^\infty w(n,p)y^p\tag{2a}\\
&=\sum_{p=1}^\infty\left(w(n-1,p-1)+\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{m=1}^pw(k-1,m)w(n-k,p-m)\right)y^p\tag{2b}\\
&=yg(n-1,y)+\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{p=m}^\infty w(k-1,m)w(n-k,p-m)y^my^{p-m}\tag{2c}\\
&=yg(n-1,y)+\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{p=0}^\infty w(k-1,m)w(n-k,p)y^my^p\tag{2d}\\
&=(y-1)g(n-1,y)+\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{p=0}^\infty w(k-1,m)w(n-k,p)y^my^p\tag{2e}\\
&=(y-1)g(n-1,y)+\sum_{k=1}^ng(k-1,y)g(n-k,y)\tag{2f}
\end{align}
$$
$\text{(2a)}$: create generating function on second variable
$\text{(2b)}$: use $(1)$
$\text{(2c)}$: use $\text{(2a)}$
$\text{(2d)}$: substitute $p\mapsto p+m$
$\text{(2e)}$: subtract $g(n-1,y)$ and add $k=1,m=0$ case, which adds $g(n-1,y)$
$\text{(2f)}$: use $\text{(2a)}$

Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
f(x,y)
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty g(n,y)x^n\tag{3a}\\
&=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty g(n,y)x^n\tag{3b}\\[5pt]
&=1+x(y-1)f(x,y)+xf(x,y)^2\tag{3c}\\[15pt]
0
&=1+(xy-x-1)f(x,y)+xf(x,y)^2\tag{3d}
\end{align}
$$
$\text{(3a)}$: create generating function on first variable
$\text{(3b)}$: break out the $n=0$ case
$\text{(3c)}$: use $\text{(2)}$
$\text{(3d)}$: subtract $f(x,y)$ from both sides

Applying the [Quadratic Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) to $(3)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
f(x,y)
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{p=0}^nw(n,p)x^ny^p\tag{4a}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{1+x(1-y)-\sqrt{(1+x(1-y))^2-4x}}{2x}\tag{4b}\\[6pt]
&=\frac1{1+x(1-y)}\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\frac{4x}{(1+x(1-y))^2}}}{\frac{2x}{(1+x(1-y))^2}}\tag{4c}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Closed Form for the General Term**

The [Binomial Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) says
$$
\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}x^k\tag{5}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{x^k}{(1+x(1-y))^{2k+1}}
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty(-1)^j\binom{2k+j}{j}x^{j+k}(1-y)^j\tag{6a}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{i=0}^j(-1)^{i+j}\binom{2k+j}{2k}\binom{j}{i}x^{j+k}y^i\tag{6b}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=i}^\infty(-1)^{i+j}\binom{2k+j}{2k}\binom{j}{i}x^{j+k}y^i\tag{6c}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty(-1)^{j}\binom{2k+j+i}{2k}\binom{j+i}{i}x^{i+j+k}y^i\tag{6d}
\end{align}
$$
$\text{(6a)}$: binomial theorem on $(1+x(1-y))^{-2k-1}$
$\text{(6b)}$: binomial theorem on $(1-y)^j$
$\text{(6c)}$: switch order of summation
$\text{(6d)}$: substitute $j\mapsto j+i$

Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
f(x,y)
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^j}{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2k+j+i}{2k}\binom{j+i}{i}x^{i+j+k}y^i\tag{7a}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=k}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{j+k}}{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{i+j+k}{2k}\binom{i+j-k}{i}x^{i+j}y^i\tag{7b}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^j\frac{(-1)^{j+k}}{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{i+j+k}{2k}\binom{i+j-k}{i}x^{i+j}y^i\tag{7c}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^j\frac{(-1)^{j+k}}{k+1}\binom{i+j}{i}\binom{i+j+k}{k}\binom{j}{k}x^{i+j}y^i\tag{7d}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^j\frac{(-1)^j}{j+1}\binom{i+j}{i}\binom{-i-j-1}{k}\binom{j+1}{k+1}x^{i+j}y^i\tag{7e}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^j\frac{(-1)^j}{j+1}\binom{i+j}{i}\binom{-i-j-1}{k}\binom{j+1}{j-k}x^{i+j}y^i\tag{7f}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^j}{j+1}\binom{i+j}{i}\binom{-i}{j}x^{i+j}y^i\tag{7g}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac1{j+1}\binom{i+j}{i}\binom{i+j-1}{j}x^{i+j}y^i\tag{7h}\\
&=\sum_{p=0}^\infty\sum_{n=p}^\infty\frac1{n-p+1}\binom{n}{p}\binom{n-1}{n-p}x^ny^p\tag{7i}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{p=0}^n\frac1{n-p+1}\binom{n}{p}\binom{n-1}{n-p}x^ny^p\tag{7j}\\
&=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{p=1}^n\frac1{n-p+1}\binom{n}{p}\binom{n-1}{p-1}x^ny^p\tag{7k}\\
&=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{p=1}^n\color{#C00000}{\frac1{n}\binom{n}{p}\binom{n}{p-1}}x^ny^p\tag{7l}\\
\end{align}
$$
$\text{(7a)}$: use $(4)$, $(5)$, and $(6)$
$\text{(7b)}$: substitute $j\mapsto j-k$
$\text{(7c)}$: switch order of summation
$\text{(7d)}$: both binomial products equal $\binom{i+j+k}{i,j-k,k,k}$
$\text{(7e)}$: $(-1)^k\binom{i+j+k}{k}=\binom{-i-j-1}{k}$ and $\frac1{k+1}\binom{j}{k}=\frac1{j+1}\binom{j+1}{k+1}$
$\text{(7f)}$: $\binom{j+1}{k+1}=\binom{j+1}{j-k}$
$\text{(7g)}$: Vandermonde Identity
$\text{(7h)}$: $(-1)^j\binom{-i}{j}=\binom{i+j-1}{j}$
$\text{(7i)}$: substitute $j\mapsto n-i$ then $i\mapsto p$
$\text{(7j)}$: switch order of summation
$\text{(7k)}$: pull out $n=0$ case, then $\binom{n-1}{n-p}=\binom{n-1}{p-1}$, then remove $p=0$ case
$\text{(7l)}$: $\binom{n-1}{p-1}=\frac{n-p+1}{n}\binom{n}{p-1}$

Thus, by equating coefficients in $(7)$,
$$
w(n,p)=\frac1n\binom{n}{p}\binom{n}{p-1}\tag{8}
$$

---

**Ignoring Peaks**

If we don't care to count peaks, we can sum over $p$ to get the number of unilateral walks of type $n$:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{p=1}^n\frac1n\binom{n}{p}\binom{n}{p-1}
&=\sum_{p=1}^n\frac1n\binom{n}{n-p}\binom{n}{p-1}\tag{9a}\\
&=\frac1n\binom{2n}{n-1}\tag{9b}\\
&=\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}\tag{9c}
\end{align}
$$
$\text{(9a)}$: $\binom{n}{p}=\binom{n}{n-p}$
$\text{(9b)}$: Vandermonde Identity
$\text{(9c)}$: $\binom{2n}{n-1}=\frac{n}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$

where $\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$ is the $n^\text{th}$ [Catalan number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

Comment: Please read the question again.Let k=2 n=6 the 6th catalan number will count in sequences with more that 2 number of violations too which are not required.PS: a violation is an instance when a 1 is IMMEDIATELY followed by a 0.

Comment: how to we calculate when the allowed violations are exactly k,that was the question

Comment: @user103260: I didn't see that. I have looked into it, but it seems a lot harder (or needs a different approach). I will continue to look.

Comment: @user103260: I have updated my answer. It still uses generating functions, but arrives at the answer for your actual question.